# How can I separate the y=fill bars in a ggplot2 grouped barchart if they have been lumped together?

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill, grouped-bar-chart

The bars which represent precipitation sums of a season ("Frühling") for each year ("Jahr") ended up lumped into one bar per group (30 years in each of the two reference periods "refp"). Actually, they should be displayed as 30 bars next to each other grouped as "refp1" and after a small space or in another box then 30 bars next to each other grouped as "refp2". I have struggled too many hours now and am still totally clueless.

Even though I followed the instructions of https://www.statology.org/grouped-barplot-in-r/, x=refp worked nicely but the fill=Jahr year bars did not appear next to each other.

This is what the middle of my data frame, at the transition between refp1 and refp2, [looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhiVI.jpg)

A small code to reproduce the relevant columns of this part would be:

```
Jahr <- c(1988,1989,1990,1991,1992)
Fruehling <- c(100,75,110,100,150)
refp <- c("refp1","refp1","refp1","refp2","refp2")
refps <- data.frame(Jahr,Fruehling,refp)
```

1. With:

```
ggplot(refps, aes(fill=Jahr, y=Fruehling, x=refp))+geom_bar(position='dodge',stat='identity')
```

[this happened.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxfFv.png)

2. With:

```
ggplot(refps, aes(Jahr,Fruehling,facet_wrap(~refp)))+geom_col()
```

the two reference periods "refp1" and "refp2" are [no longer separated by a space.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBdWK.png)

3. Using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59869757/how-to-order-grouped-bars-in-a-ggplot2-barplot-categorically-and-consistently):

```
ggplot(data=refps, aes(factor(refp), y=Fruehling, fill=as.factor(Jahr))) + 
     geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")`
```

it [got closer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN4gr.png) though I had rather the years beneath the bars instead of individually in the legend and only in one colour per refp group.

I could reduce my expectations and plot everything on its own similar to 2) or use the suggestion shown in 3). But I am really puzzled and would appreciate it a lot if you could explain to me why in 1) with geom_bar the years get lumped in spite of position = 'dodge' and how to get them separate.

Comment: `ggplot(refps, aes(refp, Fruehling, fill = Jahr, group = Jahr)) + geom_col(position = position_dodge())`

Comment: Yes! The ´group = Jahr´ is what I'd been missing to separate the bars because the default mapping had failed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is using facet like this

```r
library(ggplot2)
Jahr <- c(1988,1989,1990,1991,1992)
Fruehling <- c(100,75,110,100,150)
refp <- c("refp1","refp1","refp1","refp2","refp2")
refps <- data.frame(Jahr,Fruehling,refp)

ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = refps, mapping = aes(x=Jahr, y=Fruehling), 
           position='dodge',stat='identity') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(Jahr), max(Jahr), by =1)) +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(refp), scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That's good, thank you. The only little issue is - I clarified my question now - that there should not be all the empty years in both refp group but just a small separating space. Looked up `?facet_grid` and cutting out empty years was possible with scales="free_x".
`ggplot() + 
geom_bar(data = refps, mapping = aes(x=Jahr, y=Fruehling), position='dodge',stat='identity') +
facet_grid(cols = vars(refp),scales="free_x")´

Comment: With the free_x there is potention mis_match between bar size across facet... I updated the answer a bit.